# Download CSV in Python - File created when link is activated

Tags: python, csv, download, python-requests

I'm trying to create a script that can gather financial data from my accounting software daily. Trouble is that the link where I can download a CSV only generates the CSV when the link is activated. The link does not point to a specific file hosted anywhere but rather generates and downloads the file when the link is pressed. 
The specific data I need is not available through the API, and I'm forced to download it through their interface daily to keep my database updated with financial data.

I have tried several variations using the requests lib but nothing works as no file is referenced.

The link to the file generator looks like this:
[https://app.dinero.dk/api/{CompanyID}/2019-01/result?includeSummaryAccount=false&fmt=csv&timeperiod=&showZeroAccount=false&showAccountNo=false&showVatType=false&includeLedgerEntries=false&includeComparison=true](https://app.dinero.dk/api/%7BCompanyID%7D/2019-01/result?includeSummaryAccount=false&fmt=csv&timeperiod=&showZeroAccount=false&showAccountNo=false&showVatType=false&includeLedgerEntries=false&includeComparison=true)

Is there any way to activate the link and catch the downloaded file?

Added bonus problem: I need to be logged in to activate the link. Can I pass authentication through a header like when calling an API?

Answer (score 0):

there is this pypi package called [pySmartDL](https://pypi.org/project/pySmartDL/)

install it using: `$ pip3 install pySmartDL --user`

usage in python3:

```
from pySmartDL import SmartDL
url = 'https://github.com/iTaybb/pySmartDL/raw/master/test/7za920.zip'
dest = '~/Downloads/'

obj = SmartDL(url, dest) 
obj.start()

path = obj.get_dest()
```

it also shows the download progress

good luck ;)